# If any $15$ cars have $3$ with the same manufacturer, prove that any $100$ cars have $15$ with the same manufacturer.

Tags: combinatorics

I was solving some combinatorics question and I came upon one I've been trying to solve for 2 days and I'm curios how to solve it.

It is known that in every set of 15 cars, at least 3 were manufactured from the same country (there can also be another 3 (or more) cars in the set which came from another country). prove that in every set of 100 cars, 15 were made manufactured in the same country.

Thanks to anyone who helps!

Comment: Experiment with different numbers of countries. For example, if there are $10$ countries, can you construct a set of $15$ cars that don't contain $3$ cars from the same country?

Comment: This is an application of the Pigeonhole Principle. Note that if there were, say, 8 countries, then you would be able to create a set of 15 cars in which no more than two cars are from a particular country: just have 2 cars made in each of the first 7 countries, and 1 car in the last country. So, figure out the largest possible number of countries that can manufacture cars on the basis of the information you are given, and then use the Pigeonhole Principle to derive the desiredc conclusion.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin it is a bit more subtle: the first 7 countries may not have 2 cars each.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin but doesn't it have to work for any number of countries?

Comment: @LinAlg: I do not understand your comment. My point is that if there were 8 countries, then it would not be true that "in every set of 15 cars, at least 3 were manufactured from the same country", because there is one possible collection of 15 cars in which that would be false. What exactly is your point, then?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin "just have 2 cars made in each of the first 7 countries" Who said there are at least 2 cars made in each of these countries?

Comment: @Vladislav: As I note below: you are reading the problem as describing a fixed set of cars; I am reading the problem as describing a fixed set of countries. The two approaches are equivalent and reach the same conclusions. Any specific set of cars that you find in which you can find a set of 15 cars in which no three were made by the same country will also have a set of at least 8 countries making cars.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin the two approaches are not equivalent because you have the hidden _assumption_ that, if a country can make a car, then it can also make a second car.  This may be true about cars in the real world, but is perhaps false about e.g. A-bombs in the real world during e.g. 1950s-60s.  Anyway the question does not say you can assume that.

Comment: @antkam: Sorry, but that is just not true. What I'm doing is showing that you cannot construct a counterexample, but I'm doing so by considering the set of countries that would be involved in a (potential) counterexample.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - the OP claim is true, so of course one cannot construct a counter-example. we're saying your _proof_ is invalid because it has an additional hidden assumption. E.g. imagine a world where 12 different countries have the resources to make only 1 car each, and a 13th country can make any number of cars. (Again, for A-bombs this might actually make sense.) Then it is true that "any set of 15 cars have 3 from same country" and also "any set of 100 cars have 15 from same country". But your proof goes: "It is impossible to have 8 or more manufacturing countries..." which is wrong.

Comment: @antkam: And in that world, it is **trivial** that the conclusion holds, **regardless** of the assumption. So this is a case that need not be considered.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Well then you should have mentioned, in your written proof, that "the case where 12 countries can produce 1 car each" is trivial, and admit that the rest of your proof considers only the non-trivial case.  But how many such cases would you need to add and declare as trivial?  Can you list them all, thereby clearly delineating the scope of your non-trivial treatment?  Perhaps you can see better than the rest of us all the "trivial" cases... but I sure cannot right away.

Comment: @antkam: Any case with more countries is even easier to dismiss, from the point of view of pigeonholing. The countries are the pigeonholes, the  cars are the pigeons. The more pigeonholes there are, the easier it is to distribute the pigeons in a way in which there are fifteen pigeons with no three of them in the same hole. The hardest case to consider is the one with the least number of pigeonholes that could potentially lead to a counterexemple.

Comment: @antkam: see final paragraph in the edit.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - This is not the first time a math professor (such as you) shows a proof and leaves a few "trivial" cases not covered, and I struggled with "But why are these trivial?"  :)  I did not read your amendments in detail, but I trust you can cover those "trivial" cases you did not cover before.  Lets maybe agree we have a different definition of what constitutes "trivial" in the first place.

Comment: @antkram: All you need to read is the final paragraph to see why the extreme case is the only one that needs considering.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a set $A$ of $100$ cars such that no $15$ are manufactured in the same country; we will show that there must be a subset of $15$ cars no three of which are from the same country.

So consider any hypothetical particular subset $S\subset A$.

1) No country has contributed more than $14$ cars to $A$, since if it had, then choose $15$ cars among that country's produce, and you violated the definition of $A$.

2) The countries contributing to $A$ can be divided into $n_1$ countries contributing just one car, and $n_2$ countries contributing between $2$ and $14$ cars.  $n_1 + 14n_2 \geq 100$.

3) If $n_2>7$ we can choose $2$ cars from each of those countries for $S$, and this violates the rule that every $S$ of 15 cars contains three or more cars from the same country. So $n_2 \leq 7$.

4) $n_1 \geq 100 - 14 n_2 \geq 100 - 98 = 2$. So if $n_2 = 7$ we can choose for $S$ two cars from each of those seven countries and one car from an $n_1$ country,  and this violates the rule that every $S$ of 15 cars contains three or more cars from the same country.  So $n_2 < 7$.

5)  If $n_2 \leq 6$ then $n_1 \geq 100 - 14 n_2 \geq 100 - 84 = 16$. Thus if $n_2 < 7$ we can form a set $S$ of more than $15$ cars no *two* of which are from the same country, again violating the rules.

6) Therefore whenever we have a set of $100$ cars no $15$ of which are from the same country, we can form a set $S$ of $15$ cars no $3$ of which are from the same country.

Comment: The first part of 4) up to "So" can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be the number of countries who made exactly one car appearing in the $100$.
Let $m$ be the number of countries who made more than one car appearing in the $100$.

Assume by way of contradiction that no country made $15$ cars. Then $$n+14m\ge 100,$$ because $n$ countries contribute $1$ car each and $m$ countries contribute at most $14$ each, and $$n+2m\le 14,$$ for otherwise selecting one car from the $n$ countries and two from the $m$ countries would give $15$ cars with no three alike. Therefore,
$$
(n+14m)-(n+2m)\ge 100-14\implies 12m\ge 86\implies m\ge \lceil 86/12\rceil = 8
$$
But this is a contradiction, because selecting two cars from eight of the countries with more than one car would give $16$ cars with no three alike.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** See the very final paragraph for the same argument, but starting from the other end. Perhaps that will clarify.

---

It is impossible for there to be 8 or more manufacturing countries. If there were 8 or more manufacturing countries, then you could have a set of 15 cars in which no country made 3 or more cars: you could have each of the first 7 countries manufacture two of the cars, and the final country manufacture exactly 1 car. That means that if there were 8 or more manufacturing countries, the hypothesis ("in every set of 15 cars at least 3 were manufactured in the same country") would not be true.

Thus, the maximum number of manufacturing countries is 7. If there are 7 or fewer manufacturing countries, then by the pigeonhole principle, if we are distributing 100 items among (at most) 7 "boxes" (the countries), then at least one box contains 15 or more items (since otherwise, you would have at most $14\times 7 = 98$ items).

---

In light of comments, let me clarify what this approach is doing.

There are two ways to read the problem: either as describing a specific run of cars made by an unknown number of countries, or as describing a specific set of manufacturing countries that make runs of productions of cars.

In essence: I'm showing that it is impossible to construct a counterexample by considering the number of countries involved. Other approaches show that it is impossible to have a counterexample by considering the cars involved. The two approaches amount to the same thing, because a potential counterexample would be "detected" by either approach.

---

Sigh; apparently, this is creating way more controversy than it should. I do not dispute other approaches, but apparently some people are having issues with this approach.

What the approach does is show that no counterexample can exist; that is, we cannot have a set of cars in which the premise holds but not the conclusion. I do this by attempting to build such a counterexample, but showing that none can be made. I attempt to build such a counterexample by considering the number of countries that would be included in such a counterexample.

When I say "you could have a set of 15 cars in which no country made 3 or more cars: you could have each of the first 7 countries manufacture two of the cars, and the final country make exactly one car", how does that fit into a potential counterexample? It tells you that if you have a particular run in which there are 8 or more manufacturing countries, then you would *either* trivially satisfy the conclusion, or else fail to satisfy the hypothesis; the situation described is the extreme case, where it is least clear that the hypothesis may fail (*obviously*, if we knew there are 15 or more manufacturing countries we would know the premise fails, etc). Any larger number of countries make it easier to construct a subset of 15 with no more than 2 from the same country. So in a search for a potential counterexample (with 100+ cars), we may restrict to the case in which there are no more than 7 manufacturing countries.

It's just that I'm thinking about "building a counterexample" as countries pumping out cars to whatever specification, rather than "we have a bunch of cars, let's figure out who made them."

Any potential counterexample would be detected by this approach. The fact that this approach does not detect a counterexample shows that no counterexample exists.

Let me do the same argument, but starting with the "fewer countries" case first.

If a counterexample set of 100 cars involved 7 or fewer countries, then we would get at most 98 cars (14 cars each for the at most 7 countries); so the counterexample involves 8 or more countries. On the other hand, if you had 8 or more countries, and exactly $k\leq 7$ make at least 2 cars, and at least $15-2k$ make exactly one, you fail the assumption; so if we have exactly $k$ making at least 2 cars, and at most $14-2k$ make exactly $1$ car, then you still need to distribute $100- (2k) - (14-2k) = 86$ cars among the $k$ countries that make at least $2$ cars. If we are to avoid going over $14$ for any given country, we want $k$ to be as large as possible. The largest possible is $7$ with $1$ country making exactly 1 car, which is the case I opened with.

I originally did the same thing, but did it in the other order, by first dismissing the counterexamples with 8 or more countries, then noting no counterexample can have 7 or fewer.

Comment: "You could have each of the first $7$ countries manufacture two cars..." What if some of these countries only made one car appearing tin the set of 100? The cars are already made, you cannot have the countries manufacture two cars.

Comment: @Mike Earnest: You are reading the problem as "There is a collection of an unknown number of cars; this collection has the following properties." I am reading the problem as "There is a collection of an unknown number of countries making cars. This collection has the following properties." The two approaches are, in essence, equivalent and reach the same conclusions.

Comment: It is not a matter of reading. The case when one of the first 7 countries has only 1 car made ruins your proof.

Comment: @Vladislav: Are you objecting to me saying they are "the first 7", and not "some 7"? Surely not. The countries are interchangeable and I can order them any way I want. You really are objecting to me treating the problem as describing an arbitrary run of production rather than a fixed set of cars. Is that not the case?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin "The countries are interchangeable and I can order them any way I want." Sure you can, but you need to prove that there are 7 countries produced at least 2 cars. You didn't. And the problem doesn't describe the "run of production" anyhow, it makes statements about sets of cars and countries.

Comment: In your reading of the problem, where there is a collection of countries with certain properties, what are those properties specifically?

Comment: @MikeEarnest: In any particular (sufficiently large) run of production of cars, any subset of 15 contains three made by the same country.

Comment: @Vladislav: In short, "yes", you are objecting to treating the problem as describing a fixed set of countries and giving properties of an arbitrary run of production. Could have just said so. Under the reading I am taking, I do not need to "prove that there are 7 countries [that] produced at least 2 cars each." So... no, your objection lies elsewhere, not where you think it does.

Comment: The problem with your interpretation is that you implicitly _assumed_ that a country that can manufacture a car can also manufacture a second car.  In the real world this is 99.9999999% true(?), but it is not justified by the wording of the OP question.  (And if we're talking about H-bombs, not cars, then the assumption is probably false even in the real world.)  Your proof relies on this assumption, and therefore is a weaker theorem (and in our opinion don't meet the OP specification).  The other Answers don't rely on this assumption, and are therefore stronger.

Comment: @antkam: What I'm doing is showing that you cannot construct a counterexample, by considering the set of countries that would make up a potential counterexample. The other answers show that you cannot construct a counterexample from the other end. They amount to the exact same thing, approached from different ends.

Comment: You hid away important details in the "etc" of your "dismiss as trivial" paragraph, so I still argue this answer is incomplete. If you want to look at the problem from another angle, you have to prove it is OK to do so, and proving that in this case is about half the work.

Comment: @Mike Earnest: I disagree. I'm showing that you cannot construct a counterexample.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Then you need you to show that every set that satisfies the problems constraint might be constructively obtained.

Comment: @Vladislav: Did you look at the (now penultimate) paragraph in the edited answer? It's the same argument but describing the analysis in the other order. I *did* prove it, but you are getting hung up in the language I used to describe it.